# Tool that can automatically save picture from website

Tags: download, automation, website

Is there any tool that can automatically download the picture from the website (like Bing.com background picture)? Not necessary to automate totally, just to make the save process more easier. (I wish to save those for my own wallpaper, and change randomly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bing Downloader](http://bing.codeplex.com/) is one of such tool to automate wallpaper download from Bing.com. You need to schedule the execution using some schedulers.

Answer (score 3):

[HTTrack Website Copier](http://www.httrack.com/) is able to download entire websites and is highly filterable so can be very easily set up to only download the images you want.

Answer (score 2):

[DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/201/) lets you easily download all of the images and videos on a page, or just selected ones. Its main purpose is as a download manager, but it would work perfectly for what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows 7 then you can set the desktop background to a slideshow based on the RSS feed from Bing or any other photo stream (Flickr for example)

Instructions are available [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-set-a-bing-wallpaper-desktop-slideshow-in-windows-7/)

I have done this and have a slideshow background of [Stuck In Customs](http://www.flickr.com/photos/stuckincustoms)'s Flickr feed.

Answer (score 0):

Firebug's Net pane can show you the URL of all images that are being loaded. From there you can right-click on one, load it in a new tab, and save it.

Answer (score 0):

In IE you can right click on the background AND select 'Save Background As'

In firefox right click the background and select 'View Background Image'

This works assuming the page has a background image...